# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un correcto singleton para una conexión a mysqli?

Tags: mysqli

Ejemplo del error:

> mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in

```
class Model
{

  private $db_host ;
  private $db_user ;
  private $db_pass ;
  private $db_name ;
  private $db_charset;
  private $connection;
  private static $instance;


  public function __construct(){
    try {
      $this->setConnetion();
      $this->runConnection();
    } catch (ExceptionSicatsem $e) {
      echo $e::__toString();
    }
  }

  private function setConnetion(){
    require 'app/config/datosDeConexion.php';

    $this->db_host = $datos_conexion['db_host'];
    $this->db_user = $datos_conexion['db_user'];
    $this->db_pass = $datos_conexion['db_pass'];
    $this->db_name = $datos_conexion['db_name'];
    $this->db_charset = $datos_conexion['db_charset'];
  }

  private function runConnection(){

    $this->connection = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
    if(!$this->connection){
      throw new ExceptionSicatsem("Error al intentar conectar con la base de datos");
    }else {
        $this->connection->set_charset($this->db_charset);
    }
  }



  public static function getInstance(){
    if(static::$instance === null){
      static::$instance = new Model();
    }
    return static::$instance;
  }


  public function query($sql){
    if($this->connection->connect_errno){
      die('Error de Conexión (' . $this->connection->error . ') ');
    }else {
      return $this->connection->query($sql);
    }

  }


  public function rowsQuery($result){
    if(isset($result) && is_resource($result)){
     return $result->num_rows();
   }
  }


  public function rowsOpe(){
    if($this->connection->connect_errno){
      die('Error de Conexión (' . $this->connection->error . ') ');
    }else {
      return $this->connection->affected_rows;
    }
  }


  public function liberar($result){
    if(isset($result) && is_resource($result)){
       $result->free_result();
    }
  }


  public function listNum($query){
    if(isset($query)){
      return $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
    }
  }


  public function listAssoc($query){
    if(isset($query)){
      return  $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
  }

  public function listNumAssoc($query){
    if(isset($query)){
      return $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    }
  }

  public function close(){
    if(!$this->connection) {
        die('Error de Conexión (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
    } else{
      $this->connection->close();
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: ¿Qué problema tienes? ¿Cómo podemos reproducirlo? ¿Tienes algún ejemplo de uso de tu clase?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando llamo el metodo getInstance siempre me retorna un "null"

Comment: Esta noche trato de reproducirlo. Simplemente me falta saber cómo llamas exactamente al `getInstance()` (edita tu respuesta y pon un ejemplo) y ya tendré todo para reproducir el problema. Teóricamente te devuelve `null` porque haces `$this->connection`, que crea una propiedad de clase en la que guardar la conexión en vez de modificar el valor estático (si no pones el `this`). Modificalo y me dices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He tratado de reproducir tu error y me he encontrado con varios errores que he ido comentando en el código.

- Las excepciones deberían propagarse hacia arriba y ser capturadas por el nivel superior de la aplicación.
- La forma de comprobar una mala conexión no era correcta. Un `new mysqli(..)` siempre va a crear una instancia, pero ésta contendrá información de error que hay que comprobar.
- La forma en la que mostrabas la información de la excepción no era correcta, llamabas a `__toString` de manera estática (usando `::` en vez de `->`). Hay que usar, por ejemplo, `Exception::getMessage()` haciendo la llamada al método de la clase, por ejemplo `$e->getMessage()` y no `$e::getMessage()`.

Aquí tienes el código corregido:

```
<?php
class Model
{
    private $db_host ;
    private $db_user ;
    private $db_pass ;
    private $db_name ;
    private $db_charset;
    private $connection;
    private static $instance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        /* Permitimos la propagación de la excepción */
        //try {
            $this->setConnetion();
            $this->runConnection();
        //} catch (Exception $e) {
        //    /* __toString() no debe ser llamado estáticamente */
        //    echo $e->getMessage();
        //}
    }

    private function setConnetion()
    {
        require 'datosDeConexion.php';

        $this->db_host = $datos_conexion['db_host'];
        $this->db_user = $datos_conexion['db_user'];
        $this->db_pass = $datos_conexion['db_pass'];
        $this->db_name = $datos_conexion['db_name'];
        $this->db_charset = $datos_conexion['db_charset'];
    }

    private function runConnection()
    {
        $this->connection = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
        /* El operador new siempre devuelve una instancia del objeto solicitado */
        if ($this->connection->connect_error) {
            throw new Exception(
                'Error al intentar conectar con la base de datos (' . $this->connection->connect_error . ')'
            );
        } else {
            $this->connection->set_charset($this->db_charset);
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (static::$instance === null) {
            static::$instance = new Model();
        }
        return static::$instance;
    }

    public function query($sql)
    {
        if ($this->connection->connect_errno) {
            die('Error de Conexión (' . $this->connection->error . ') ');
        } else {
            return $this->connection->query($sql);
        }
    }

    public function rowsQuery($result)
    {
        if (isset($result) && is_resource($result)) {
            return $result->num_rows();
        }
    }

    public function rowsOpe()
    {
        if ($this->connection->connect_errno) {
            die('Error de Conexión (' . $this->connection->error . ') ');
        } else {
            return $this->connection->affected_rows;
        }
    }

    public function liberar($result)
    {
        if (isset($result) && is_resource($result)) {
            $result->free_result();
        }
    }

    public function listNum($query)
    {
        if (isset($query)) {
            return $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
        }
    }

    public function listAssoc($query)
    {
        if (isset($query)) {
            return  $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        }
    }

    public function listNumAssoc($query)
    {
        if (isset($query)) {
            return $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        }
    }

    public function close()
    {
        if (!$this->connection) {
            die('Error de Conexión (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
            $this->connection->close();
        }
    }
}

/* Pruebas de funcionamiento */
try {
    $bbdd = Model::getInstance();
    var_dump($bbdd);
    $bbdd->close();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die('Error creando singleton: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por todo!!

Comment: Fue un placer ayudar. Si te solucionó tu problema no olvides marcar la respuesta como correcta. Gracias :)